# Building changeset for entire association

Tags: elixir, ecto

I read about [cast_assoc/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3) here .But documentation looks confusing. I want to build `single changeset for the entire association` and execute it in one transaction for update. Here are my models
;

```
    defmodule User do      
     use Gallery.Web, :model


     schema "users" do   
       field(:name, :string)
       field(:occupation, :string)
       has_many(:paintings, Painting)
     end

    def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
     struct
     |> cast(params, [ :name, :occupation ])
     |> validate_required([:name, :occupation]) 
    end
   end

   defmodule Painting do      
     use Gallery.Web, :model


     schema "paintings" do   
       field(:name, :string)          
       belongs_to(:users, User)
     end

    def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
     struct
     |> cast(params, [ :name ])
     |> validate_required([:name]) 
    end
   end
```

This is the data i want to build a single changeset of

```
data= %User{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "users">,
   id: 4606,
   name: "Test",
   occupation: "Artist",
   paintings: [
     %Painting{
     __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "paintings">,
     user_id: 4606,
     id: 1515,
     name: "philip"
     },
   %Painting{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "paintings">,
    user_id: 4606,
    id: 1516,
    name: "john"
    }
  ]
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get errors with the attempts you made? Your data appears to have a number of typos (uerss, painitngs, Painitng). Maybe not relevant, but worth pointing out just in case.

Comment: @DarraghEnright sorry these are just typos. while copying code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changesets to work your data needs to be plain maps and not structs (as if you got it from params).

If you want to just insert user with multiple paintings you need to:

- get rid of structs
- get rid of ids (in case of inserts they are created on the fly)
- have a `cast_assoc` in user changeset

Like this:

```
data = %{
  name: "Test",
  occupation: "Artist",
  paintings: [
    %{
      name: "philip"
    },
    %{
      name: "john"
    }
  ]
}

%User{}
|> User.changeset(data)
|> Repo.insert
```

If you want to also update stuff in this way, it gets more complicated. It is not clear if the list of paintings in `data` should update existing paintings in place, add new ones or delete all previous ones and replace them with those in `data`. I personally wouldn't recommend nested changesets for updates. https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3

UPDATE AFTER CLARIFICATION:

To update all the paintings in place you need to do two more things. You need to:

- preload the paintings
- have the painting id in data

Like this:

```
data = %{
  name: "Test",
  occupation: "Artist",
  paintings: [
    %{
      id: 1,
      name: "philip"
    },
    %{
      id: 2,
      name: "john"
    }
  ]
}

User
|> Repo.get_by(id: user_id)
|> Repo.preload(:paintings)
|> User.changeset(data)
|> Repo.update
```

You don't need to use `Multi`. It will be one transaction. Using `Repo` module once usually indicates one database operation.

All the magic happens in the `paintings: [...]`. According to docs you have four cases:

> - If the parameter does not contain an ID, the parameter data will be passed to changeset/2 with a new struct and become an insert operation
> - If the parameter contains an ID and there is no associated child with such ID, the parameter data will be passed to changeset/2 with a
>     new struct and become an insert operation
> - If the parameter contains an ID and there is an associated child with such ID, the parameter data will be passed to changeset/2 with
>     the existing struct and become an update operation
> - If there is an associated child with an ID and its ID is not given as parameter, the :on_replace callback for that association will be
>     invoked (see the “On replace” section on the module documentation)

You are interested in case the third case for updating in place. If you don't pass all the paintings in `data` you may be also interested in fourth one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually i need it for update. and docs are confusing

Comment: @script can you elaborate on what is your use case then? Docs are confusing because it is a confusing problem. Are you updating paintings in place or adding new ones? Do you also want to delete paintings through this?

Comment: I just want to  update user and its associated paintings that are already in place. After building one single changeset i want to update user and painting in one transaction.using Ecto.Multi.